# Does folium allow a html div box that updates its value based on coordinates on the map?

Tags: javascript, python, html, dataframe, folium

im new to using folium library so pardon my ignorance
So what i am trying to achieve here is a div box that shows the speed of the vehicle travelling along the lat and lon provided.The current problem i'm facing is the speed_textbox_id is not being updated with the speed given by the dataframe.
My input is a dataframe which has the lat , lon coordinates, timestamp in epoch and speed.
The console log doesn't show any errors regarding to the javascript

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json

def df_to_line_geojson(df):
    features = []
    coordinates = []
    timestamps = []
    speeds = []  

    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        coordinates.append([row['lon'], row['lat']])
        timestamps.append(row['timestamp'])
        speed = int(row['speed']) 
        speeds.append(speed)  

    return {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": coordinates
                },
                "properties": {
                    "times": timestamps,
                    "style": {
                        "color": "blue",
                        "weight": 5
                    },
                    "speeds": speeds 
                }
            }
        ]
    }

geojson_data_dict = {}
for device_id in gps_device_ids:
    sub_sample = copy_gps_data_map[copy_gps_data_map['device_id'] == device_id]
    geojson_data = df_to_line_geojson(sub_sample)
    geojson_data_dict[device_id] = geojson_data

# Create a map with multiple TimestampedGeoJson layers
for device_id, geojson_data in geojson_data_dict.items():
    # Create a map for each trip
    m = folium.Map(location=[copy_gps_data_map['lat'].iloc[0], copy_gps_data_map['lon'].iloc[0]], zoom_start=15)

    # Generate unique IDs for the speed textbox and JavaScript function
    speed_textbox_id = f'speed-{device_id}'
    js_function_id = f'updateSpeed-{device_id}'

    # Create JavaScript code to update the speed text box
    javascript_code = f"""
    function {js_function_id}(timestamp, speed) {{
        document.getElementById('{speed_textbox_id}').textContent = 'Speed: ' + speed + ' km/h';
    }}
    """

    # Add JavaScript code to the map
    m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(f"<script>{javascript_code}</script>"))

    TimestampedGeoJson(
        geojson_data,
        period='PT10S',
        add_last_point=True,
        loop=False,
        auto_play=True,
        transition_time=1000,  # Milliseconds between timestamp updates
        time_slider_drag_update=True,  # Enable time slider drag updates
    ).add_to(m)

    # Create a text box HTML content with speed
    text_box_html = f"""
    <div style="position: absolute;
                background-color: white;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                z-index: 1000;
                bottom: 80px;
                left: 20px;">
        <span id="{speed_textbox_id}">Speed: </span><br>
    </div>
    """
    
    # Add the text box HTML content to the map
    folium.MacroElement().add_to(m)
    m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(text_box_html))

    # Save the map to an HTML file with the device_id in the filename
    m.save(f'{device_id}.html')
```

[image]